# How to create XElement with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xelement

I need to generate xml like that:

```
<urlset xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1"  xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
   <loc>http://blabla</loc>
   <video:video>
     <video:player allow_embed="yes">http://blablabla</video:player_loc>      
   </video:video>
</url>
```

I can't figure out the way to work with namespaces. I can't even create `urlset` element properly, I'm trying:

```
 XNamespace _defaultNamespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
 XNamespace _videoNameSpace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1";

 new XElement("urlset",new XAttribute(_defaultNamespace+"video",_defaultNamespace))
```

and it generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<urlset p1:video="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:p1="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
```

what's that `p1` thing?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespace attributes are in xmlns namespace, so you should use 
[`XNamespace.Xmlns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.xmlns.aspx)`+ attributeName` for declaring namespaces:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
XNamespace video = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1";
var urlset = new XElement(ns + "urlset",                
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "video", video));
```

Produces

```
<urlset xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1" 
        xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" />
```

Complete xml generation will look like:

```
var urlset = new XElement(ns + "urlset",                
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "video", video),
    new XElement(ns + "url",
        new XElement(ns + "loc", "http:/blabla"),
        new XElement(video + "video",
            new XElement(video + "player",
                new XAttribute("allow_embed", "yes"),
                "http:/blabla"))));
```